# Resend a past activity in bot framework with waterfall dialog

Tags: botframework

I have a bot with waterfall dialogs, written using adaptive dialogs. After each TextInput the user should be able to go back and edit his submission. Is it possible to send again a specific activity from the bot even though the bot has progressed in the conversation flow? Also all the activities send after the TextInput which has to be edited have to be sent again, so basically the conversation flow should reset from the TextInput the user wants to edit.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit some code into your question, along with links to any samples or documentation you're following?

Comment: I am using a declarative bot similar to this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/adaptive-dialog/21.AdaptiveBot-declarative/Samples). I tried to use Interruptions on the TextInput dialog but it didn't work, because the dialog flow keeps progressing. I also tried to create a custom dialog that extends TextInput but still didn't work.

Comment: I have a lot of TextInput dialogs, one after another. I want to send the previous TextInput (to save another answer), and then continue with the dialog from that TextInput. Basically I need to rewind the dialog flow.

Comment: Is asingh's answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it helps, but I'd also like to go to a previous step from another waterfall dialog, if it's possible.

Comment: You didn't link to a specific sample, you linked to a folder. What sample are you looking at that uses both waterfall dialogs and adaptive dialogs?

Comment: I meant to say i am using adaptive dialogs, like any of that sample. Couldn't manage to do what i intended with waterfall dialog, but managed to do something with ReplaceDialogAsync.

Comment: Are you saying you've solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using following code:

`stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] =(int)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] - 3;`

`return await IntroStepAsync(stepContext, cancellationToken);`

Where **IntroStepAsync** is the step name in your dialog and **-3** means I am at the third prompt and want to go back to the 3rd last prompt, if you want to go back to the previous step you have to put **-1** and replace **IntroStepAsync** by your previous prompt's name.

Comment: If I have multiple waterfall dialogs is it possible to unde stepIndex to go to a previous step in another dialog?

Comment: No, you can't go back to the previous step in another dialog. You can use `ReplaceDialogAsync` to go back to previous dialog.